# How can i read a list with fread?

Tags: c, linked-list, nested-lists, fread

Is this possible, what's wrong here!?

I need this to read the list of "items" that belongs inside one node of "Orcamento", and also the list of "decisores".

```
int lerDadosO(DLLIST3 *orcamentos) {
    int nOrcamentos = 0, i = 0;
    ORCAMENTO Orcamento;

    FILE *ficheiro = fopen("dadosO.bin", "rb");

    if(ficheiro != NULL) {
        fseek(ficheiro, 0L, SEEK_END);
        nOrcamentos = ftell(ficheiro) / sizeof(ORCAMENTO);
        rewind(ficheiro);
        while (i != nOrcamentos) {
            Orcamento.itens = createI();
            Orcamento.decisores = createU();
            fread(&Orcamento, sizeof(ORCAMENTO), 1, ficheiro);
//            viewI(Orcamento.itens, listarItem);
            if(insertendO(orcamentos, Orcamento) != 0) {
                printf("Ocorreu um Erro!");
                return 0;
            }
            i++;
        }
        fclose(ficheiro);
    }
    else {
        printf("Não existe nenhum ficheiro binário!");
    }
    return nOrcamentos;
}
```

Comment: What is `DLLIST3`? What is `insertendO`? How is the function called? What error or incorrect behaviour do you get? And so on. Info is too incomplete. Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as exact input, expected result and actual result. Please review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: DLLIST3 it's the data type of the list. insertendO, is to insert on the list but in the end.
I'm reading from a binary file information that i saved previouly. It's supposed to allow me to list on the screen a list of Orcamentos, and each one has a list of Items and a list of users so to say...

Comment: Repeat: [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is required. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68369905/edit) the post to update it with that info.

Comment: `fread()` is overwriting the members `Orcamento.itens` and `Orcamento.decisores` that you assigned before that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you have implemented your list system, this may be accomplished by first reading data to a buffer, than transforming that into a "list"

```c
struct record {
  int field0
  int field1;
};

int main(void) {
  // variables
  FILE *stream;               // reading data
  struct record data[length]; // writing data
  struct mylisttype *list;    // result
  ...
  // read `length` `struct record`s from `stream`
  fread(data, sizeof(struct record), length, stream);
  listfrombuffer(buffer, list);
  ...
}
```